# i have a problem with my bot (spamming messages)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I wrote a piece of code that lets the bot send a message and then after 5 seconds it will delete it and then redo this step, but when I tested it, it keep spamming with test. Here is my code :

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    let chan = client.channels.cache.get('988807641792905248')
    if (message.channel.id === "988807641792905248" ) return chan.send(`test`).then(mess => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            mess.delete()
        }, 5000)
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `function` to loop your command and adding `setTimeout` to delete and resend the message.

```js
async function repeat() { //first read of function declined
    let chan = client.channels.cache.get('988807641792905248')
    if (message.channel.id === "988807641792905248" )
       chan.send("Testing").then((msg) => { //send the message
           setTimeout(() => { //Time out for 5 seconds
                msg.delete()
                setTimeout(() => { //After 5 seconds, delete the message
                    repeat(); // then going back to function repeat()
                }, 1000) 
           }, 5000)
       })
    }
    repeat(); //First read of function not declined
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time the bot sends a message, the [`client.on('messageCreate')`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) event listener runs, because a message has been posted which leads to an infinite loop. To stop it, you could just add an if check at the top of the event listener to check if the member who posted the message was a bot or not. An example would be something like this:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return
    // ...
})
```